# Spring - Security - Trouble with authorizeRequests chain

Tags: spring, spring-security

I can't understand, how to correctly make chain of the authorizeRequests chain.

If I write

```
 http
                .addFilterBefore(characterEncodingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(cacheControllerFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin/login.html")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
```

in this case all is permitAll, including /admin/** .

If I have

```
http
                .addFilterBefore(characterEncodingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(cacheControllerFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin/login.html")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
```

in this case everything, including /admin/** requires authentication of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#authorize-requests

In my case solution is

```
http
                .addFilterBefore(characterEncodingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(cacheControllerFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin/login.html")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
```